# Fullcalendar ... how do i represent tasks with no specific ending date

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, fullcalendar

How can i represent a task in full calendar if the task has a start date and no known ending date, for example a promotion which last until the stock lasts. i wish the timeline in this case to tend to infinity.

however as this kind of promotion for a product may have impact in future pages ( too many thick lines) , is it possible that in the next pages promotions that started in other pages are represented by a dotted line or a thin line?

this fiddle is just a starting point

```
 title: 'Test1',
       start:  '2016-05-01T14:30:00',
       end:  '2016-05-06T14:30:00',
```

for example i want the task 1 to tend to infinity and in the next pages can this be represented by a thinner line ?
http://jsfiddle.net/jRFYE/548/

Answer (score 2):

Adding a custom event would work for you. Try this:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource',
  function(start, end, callback) {
    // When requested, dynamically generate a
    // repeatable event for every start day of the week.
    var events = [];
    var one_day = (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

    for (loop = start.getTime(); loop <= end.getTime(); loop = loop + one_day) {

      var column_date = new Date(loop);

      if (column_date.getDay() == 0) {
        events.push({
          title: 'infinite event',
          start: new Date(column_date),
          end: new Date(loop + one_day * 6)
        });
      }
    } // for loop

    // return events generated
    callback(events);
  });
```

Fiddle URL: http://jsfiddle.net/ashishanexpert/jRFYE/553/

*[Code reference](https://coderwall.com/p/rti-rg/jquey-fullcalendar-plugin-and-repeatable-events-and-tasks)*

Comment: hello thanks, but this is a representing a repeating task, what i want is the same task ( lets say task test 1) continues for a very long time, and if possible the default size of the task is reduced to a dotted line or a line in the next pages.

Comment: hello this is very interesting, is it possible in the next pages the height of the task ( the blue line ) decreases to a line or dotted lines? as there might be a lot of events and a lot of overlaps in the future plan?

Comment: I dont think so as we are trying to push same event in a loop. By the way, I have updated the code again a bit, have a look... :)

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a custom event

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        // put your options and callbacks here
            events: events_array,
            timeFormat: 'H(:mm)',//,      
            //defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
            eventRender: function(event, element) {               
           // ur conditoin here
           //if() task then custome event render
            element.css('height','2px');          
    }


    })
```

**UPDATED** : Forked new fiddle  [custom event](http://jsfiddle.net/jRFYE/554/)

Comment: hello Rashidnk this is very very close to what i am looking for.. is it possible to have the title inside the beginning of the line ( at the begining it is a little thicker ) then it gets thin if we click next or when the text finished. so that we can read the text.. may be by adding some kind of css background tweek behind the text? or something?

Comment: u can do with css,   element.css() , u can  modify